# Error al Ejecutar comando del cmd en vbsscript

Tags: batch, vbscript

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "runas.exe /savecred /user:administrador "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe http://192.168.1.1""
WScript.Sleep 2000
oShell.Sendkeys "Test123"
```

entiendo que le problema es la doble comillas del final de la linea 3
alguna forma de ejecutar el comando de otra manera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claramente si usamos comillas para encerrar una cadena, luego tendremos un problemas, si además queremos usarlas dentro de la propia cadena. Para evitarlo podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
Dim Cmd

Cmd = "runas.exe /savecred /user:administrador " & chr(34) & "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe http://192.168.1.1" & Chr(34)
oShell.run Cmd
```

Usamos la función `Chr(34)` para indicar el caracter 34, es decir, justamente la comilla.